# How can I put my iPhone 4 in DFU Mode if the Home button is broken and it is turned off?

Tags: iphone, hardware, repair

So basically I have a tethered reboot iOS 6.1.4 on my iPhone 4. Recently the Home button broke and now I'm unable to put it into DFU Mode to turn it on. Is there a way I can put it in DFU Mode, or maybe get iTunes to install the latest iOS on it? I just need it to turn on again so I can listen to music.

Answer (score 1):

If the home button is non-functional, and the device requires a working home button to even power up, then it seems you're in a chicken-egg situation.  There is of course software that lets you remap some other button or UI action to correspond to the home button, but if you can't get the thing turned on you're out of that realm.

I suppose you could open it up and try shorting the contacts of the home button assembly, but once you're that far into it you may as well just replace the home button or the front panel.  The home button replacement part is only a few bucks, and the whole front panel is under $20 [in the US].

Answer (score 0):

Repair the home button seems the cheapest solution.

With the digitizer working, OS working and you have accessibility enabled, you could use software to simulate a home button press.

With root ssh access, you might have other avenues due to being jailbroken, but for most people, needing DFU and a broken home button is game over - get a new device time.

Comment: I don't want a new device.

Comment: I don't want you to have one either @user1944664 - just giving you some options.